# Swap out Yubikey with working one and signing git commit

Tags: gpg, yubikey

I have a Yubikey 5C Nano that is replacing a Yubikey 4C Nano that all of a sudden stopped working. I want to sign my git commits with it. The 5C was set up on an Ubuntu Linux machine, and signs git commits fine on there. However, when I remove the yubikey from my Linux machine and replace the 4C (which was in my Macbook pro), I am unable to sign anything, because it keeps looking for the old Yubikey.

I moved the `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` to `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d.old`, ran `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`, followed by `gpg --card-status`, which gives me this (some numbers redacted):

```
Reader ...........: Yubico YubiKey OTP FIDO CCID
Application ID ...: D2760001240100000006240061130000
Application type .: OpenPGP
Version ..........: 3.4
Manufacturer .....: Yubico
Serial number ....: 24006113
Name of cardholder: Scott Johnson
Language prefs ...: en
Salutation .......:
URL of public key : [not set]
Login data .......: jaywir3@gmail.com
Signature PIN ....: not forced
Key attributes ...: rsa4096 rsa4096 rsa4096
Max. PIN lengths .: 127 127 127
PIN retry counter : 3 0 3
Signature counter : 1
KDF setting ......: on
UIF setting ......: Sign=off Decrypt=off Auth=off
Signature key ....: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 54B7
      created ....: 2023-04-27 03:55:28
Encryption key....: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 9C34
      created ....: 2023-04-27 03:55:51
Authentication key: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX 0A09
      created ....: 2023-04-27 03:56:47
General key info..: [none]
```

However, when I go to run `gpg -s /tmp/blah.txt`, it reports:

```
gpg: requesting key XXXXXXXXX54B7 from hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: no default secret key: No public key
gpg: signing failed: No public key
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly and how I might go about fixing this situation?